# How to show ProgressBar when autoComplete takes time to load?

Tags: wpf, autocomplete, progress-bar

In my applications I have used AutoCompleteTextBox to show list of users in WPF desktop based apps, but due the current implementation, we are getting data from server and then the data (name, title) display in the autocompletedropDown list. But here depends upon response from server it may delay or slow, so there is a time involve.

If the UI remains like that for certain amount of time say 1 or 2 secs, then it might give a hang feeling to the end user. 
So I want to show progress-bar in the same area where autocomplete dropdown comes. Can it be done?

Sample code I have written but don't know how to proceed...

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="ACtb" >
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock ... />
               <TextBlock ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>

<ProgressBar x:Name="ACProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="Hidden"/>
```

If someone give some idea how to achieve that would be happy. This `ACProgressBar` will be visible when we make a rest call/ or only for 1-2 secs

Answer (score 1):

AutoCompleteBox doesn't have a "populating" state, but what it does have are `Populating` and `Populated` events. A simple option would be to subclass `AutoCompleteBox` and add a property representing this state, say `IsPopulating`, which you set/unset depending on these events. Then bind the visibility of your `ProgressBar` to this property.

Rather than subclassing `AutoCompleteBox` you could consider encapsulating this functionality in an attached behaviour.

As a suggestion you might consider a "spinner" style circular loading indicator within the text field at the right side as an unobtrusive indicator, this seems to be a common style.